# Using scrapy, how to a crawl a page with checkbox that have onclick attribute?

Tags: javascript, python, onclick, scrapy, web-crawler

I am using Scrapy to crawl some data from a webpage. The page has a form which contains multiple checkboxes and drop down menus, all of which need to be selected for the form to generate a data table.
All of the checkboxes have the onClick attribute that calls a javascript code, and they are in levels of hierarchy, i.e., there are 5 main checkboxes and each of them contains 7 checkboxes as sub-category, and so on. The checkboxes have a tree structure with 4 levels.
This is one of the lowest level (leaf) checkboxes:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="mid" value="1043" id="bd_1" onclick="setGroupCheck(this)">
```

The javascript method setGroupCheck() is defined in the head tage of the page.

I tried to submit the form like this:

```
FormRequest("url", method='POST', formdata={'mid':'1043','Ins':'a'}, callback=self.parseInfoPage)
```

But it gives me the error: 500 internal server error.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 2):

The error you are getting is on the server, not in your FormRequest.  There might not be much you can do about this if you want to use Scrapy.  If you need to interact with JavaScript extensively from Python, then you'll probably need to use an alternative scraping approach.

My favorite is [Selenium](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/selenium) using [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/) as the driver because it is headless.  You can download and install both following instructions at those links.  You can then start a web driver in Python using:

```
from selenium import webdriver
browser = webdriver.PhantomJS()
browser.get(url)
```

I know this answer might seem unsatisfactory because it does not solve your problem using Scrapy, but interacting with JavaScript from Python without driving a browser is generally hard or impossible if the JavaScript gets complicated.  The JavaScript on your page sounds complicated.  If you add a link to the page you are scraping I can offer more advice, but the answer to your question really depends on the page.

Comment: My guess is that the JavaScript is actually assembling data for the POST request to the server in a way that does not directly mirror the names and values specified in the form markup.  The JavaScript might also be hiding a little secret key or something to try and stop naive scraping of the page; the server would reject POST requests that don't have a very specific structure.  You need to read through all the JavaScript and figure out what a valid POST looks like for this server.  Then you need to mimic that because Scrapy isn't going to execute the JavaScript for you.

Comment: So the bottom line is that I can't use scrapy for this page, even if I figure out how they structure the post requests?

Comment: I think you can use Scrapy exactly like you're using *if* you can figure out what their JavaScript does and mimic it.  I think you might be better off using a different tool like Selenium because it can execute the JavaScript.  I once wrote an extensive scraper in Python using mechanize only to have the site switch most of their functionality over to JavaScript that broke my scraper.  The nice thing about driving a browser is that you'll always be able to scrape the page so long as the browser can render it!

Comment: Another thought... the data you are scraping is public, government data.  If you actually need all their data you might be better off using a FOIA request instead of programming!

Comment: That's true! Yet I am doing it for my work in university and they want a code that periodically gets the latest update.